# Rails: Stay on the same page after post action fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on an order system, I passed some information about a new order from controller (`orders#confirm`) to a confirmation page using instance variable (such as `@detail`). On the confirmation page, users are supposed to confirm the information and submit a form to create the new order (`orders#create`). If the post action fails, I want it to stay on the same confirmation page and preserve all the information on the page for the user:

```
  def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)
    if verify_recaptcha(model: @order) && @order.save
      redirect_to items_url
    else
      render :confirm
    end
  end
```

The code is not working because all the variables that I passed from `orders#confirm` to the confirmation page are lost. I know I can recreate them, but is there any better ways to preserve those information? Thank you very much!

Comment: can you post your code for the orders_controller confirm action please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your approach, you have to *rebuild* the `@detail` object in the current action `create` in order to make your `confirm.html.erb` view to be rendered properly.

It is possible. However, I think there is a better way that you can let the user confirms the order by AJAX ( which is dead simple with Rails ) so the user can stay on the page if the confirmation failed.

In your `confirm.html.erb`, suppose you have a form to let user confirm, just change it to `remote: true`

```
<%= form_for @order, remote: true, format: :js do |form| %>
  <%# blah blah %>
<% end %>
```

Modify your controller

```
def create
  @order = Order.new(order_params)
  if verify_recaptcha(model: @order) && @order.save
    # Redirect when success
    render js: "window.location = '#{your_desired_path}'"
  else
    # Display error to user.
    render "ajax_create_error", status: :bad_request
  end
end
```

Now you can create a file name `ajax_create_error.js.erb` to display error to the user

```
# app/views/your_controller_name/ajax_create_error.js.erb
alert("Cannot create order");
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works great. But I'm wondering if it's possible to use `flash[:danger]` to display the error message? I just want to keep it consistent with other pages

Comment: @Seraph Yes, you still can use `flash` in the `js.erb` file as normal `html.erb` file.

Comment: May I ask how to achieve it? I tried to add `<%= flash[:danger] = "Cannot create order" %>` into the `js.erb` file with no luck. It could not show the error message on the confirmation page, but displayed the error message on the next page I redirect to, which behaves exactly same as putting `flash[:danger] = "Cannot create order" ` in the controller

Comment: You should assign the flash in the controller, and print it out at `js.erb` by `alert("<%= flash[:danger] %>")`

Comment: Still not working... But thank you very much for your help!